# How to programmatically set font to labels

Tags: iphone, xcode

How to set fonts to labels in Xcode 4?

I tried this

```
mylabel.setfont = @"DBLCDTempBlack";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This

```
[mylabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"fontname" size:128.0]];
```

Answer (score 7):

use one of following

```
[mylabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13]];
[mylabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13]];//or use this
myLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13]];//or
 mylabel.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13]//or

[mylabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DBLCDTempBlack" size:128.0]];
```

also some other ways see developer documentation for creating UIFont

Answer (score 3):

you need to use this syntax:

```
[mylabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DBLCDTempBlack" size:12.0f]];
```

you should pass a UIFont object to the function setFont. You can use some of this from http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIFont

```
fontWithName:size:
systemFontOfSize:
boldSystemFontOfSize:
italicSystemFontOfSize:
```